# What is wrong with the way I am setting up my axios call?

Tags: javascript, axios

This way is working:

```
const axiosResult = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  data: {
    skus: [product.vendor_sku]
  }
});
```

This way is not:

```
const axiosResult = await axios.post(
  url,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    data: {
      skus: [product.vendor_sku]
    }
  }
);
```

What is wrong with the 2nd method where I am using `post` method directly?

Comment: I have to ask you: What's wrong with the second example? Are you getting a error? if so what is it? Is the requesting not getting through? What is the question here?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck Sorry, should have told. By 'works' I mean I get proper results back as `200`. And, the 'non-working` way gives back `400 Bad Request`. So, my token must not be getting accepted the 2nd way maybe? So, I m trying to see if I am not using `axios.post()` correctly somehow. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's like this.

```
const axiosResult = await axios.post(
  url,
  {
    skus: [product.vendor_sku]
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not about `method: "post"` and `axios.post` both are same and work fine. 
You made mistake here in 2nd one

```
{
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    data: 
  }
```

in same parenthesis `{}` you put both data and headers just change it to

```
const axiosResult = await axios.post(
      url,
     {
       skus : [product.vendor_sku]
     },
     {
       headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    }

);
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax mistake in my answer it's updated now.